# No header in Letter

Tags: letters, scrlttr2

I have a MWE, But i want no rule and Name Adress etc on the right side of the document. I just want have it on the leftside ruled. But I did not achieved it. Is this possible?

- Meaning I want this: [image]
- But not this: [image]

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  paper=a4,
  parskip=half,
  enlargefirstpage=on,    % More space on first page
  fromalign=right,        % PLacement of name in letter head
  fromphone=on,           % Turn on phone number of sender
  fromrule=aftername,     % Rule after sender name in letter head
  fromemail=true,         % <===========================================
  addrfield=on,           % Adress field for envelope with window
  backaddress=on,         % Sender address in this window
  subject=beforeopening,  % Placement of subject
  locfield=narrow,        % Additional field for sender
  foldmarks=on,           % Print foldmarks
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily \LARGE}
%\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small
%\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
%\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries}
%\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Musterfrau}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Musterstrasse 9\\12345 Ort}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49\,12\,34\,56\,789}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{max.musterfrau@web.de} 
\setkomavar{signature}{(Max Musterfrau)}
\setkomavar{place}{Ort}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
%\usepackage{marvosym} % <================================================
\setkomavar{phoneseparator}{~} % <========================================
\setkomavar{emailseparator}{~} % <========================================

\begin{document}
\renewcaptionname{english}\emailname{~} % <=========================
\renewcaptionname{english}\phonename{~} % <=======================
\begin{letter}{To: Claire Laterfield}
\setkomavar{subject}{Anschreiben}
\opening{Dear Claire,}
I am writing this letter because I have nothing better to do.

\closing{Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it `firsthead=false`, what you are searching for?

Comment: I just understand it that i have to suppress the firsthead! It is! Thank you

Comment: I've added an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want the letter head at the first page. So the options

```latex
  fromalign=right,        % PLacement of name in letter head
  fromphone=on,           % Turn on phone number of sender
  fromrule=aftername,     % Rule after sender name in letter head
  fromemail=true,         % <===========================================
```

do not make any sense, but you want either option `firsthead=false` or `\setkomavar{firsthead}{}`.

I would recommend to use the first one:

```latex
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  paper=a4,
  parskip=half,
  enlargefirstpage=on,    % More space on first page
  firsthead=false,        % Don't use a letter head at the first page.
  addrfield=on,           % Adress field for envelope with window
  backaddress=on,         % Sender address in this window
  subject=beforeopening,  % Placement of subject
  locfield=narrow,        % Additional field for sender
  foldmarks=on,           % Print foldmarks
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily \LARGE}
%\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small
%\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
%\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries}
%\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Musterfrau}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Musterstrasse 9\\12345 Ort}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49\,12\,34\,56\,789}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{max.musterfrau@web.de} 
\setkomavar{signature}{(Max Musterfrau)}
\setkomavar{place}{Ort}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
%\usepackage{marvosym} % <================================================
\setkomavar{phoneseparator}{~} % <========================================
\setkomavar{emailseparator}{~} % <========================================
%\setkomavar{firsthead}{}% YOU CAN ALSO USE THIS INSTEAD OF firsthead=false.
\begin{document}
\renewcaptionname{english}\emailname{~} % <=========================
\renewcaptionname{english}\phonename{~} % <=======================
\begin{letter}{To: Claire Laterfield}
\setkomavar{subject}{Anschreiben}
\opening{Dear Claire,}
I am writing this letter because I have nothing better to do.

\closing{Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See Figure 4.10 for a schematic display of the usage of the variables.

BTW: Some of your options are default, nevertheless I not removed them.